# Git Failed to connect to github port 443 - from ubuntu in vmware, network config is bridge

Tags: github, vmware

Q: I installed ubuntu 14.10 in VmwarePlayer, and the host is Win7, the network configure is Bridge. Then I tried to clone from github, and I got failed to connect to github 443 error.

```
Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

Then, I changed the network configure to NAT, and it succeeded to clone from github.

```
Cloning into 'docker'...
remote: Counting objects: 118355, done.
Receiving objects:  19% (22717/118355), 9.73 MiB | 77.00 KiB/s    s
```

I wonder why it doesn't work under Bridge mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [VMWare doc mentions](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html):

> If you want to connect to the Internet or other TCP/IP network using the host computer's dial-up networking or broadband connection and you are not able to give your virtual machine an IP address on the external network, NAT is often the easiest way to give your virtual machine access to that network.

[image: https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/img/nat_1_t.png]

> NAT also allows you to connect to a TCP/IP network using a Token Ring adapter on the host computer.

**[Bridge](http://websistent.com/vmware-bridged-networking/)** is more for accessing the LAN (10.x.x.x), not the WAN (where NAT gives you 192.168.x.x, and the host acts as a gateway). It is usually "Host only".

[image: http://websistent.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/vmware-bridge-network-diagram-300x127.png]